# PLS-00302: component 'COMP_FOR_OLTP' must be declared

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c

I'm trying to execute compression script GET_COMPRESSION_RATIO [from here](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/dbms_compression-11gr2): 
And this line gives me an error:

```
comptype => DBMS_COMPRESSION.comp_for_oltp,
```

> PLS-00302: component 'COMP_FOR_OLTP' must be declared

In oracle documentation, they say "The DBMS_COMPRESSSION package is owned by user SYS, and must be created by SYS. The execution privilege is granted to PUBLIC. Subprograms in this package are executed using the privileges of the current user."

I granted PUBLIC role to my user but don't know how to create  this package by SYS user. Or the problem lays somewhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using wrong scripts for Oracle 11g. Correct ones for 12c can be found [here](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/dbms_compression-enhancements-12cr1).

Answer (score 1):

The terminology changed in 12c. See the constants [here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_compress.htm#ARPLS72894).

You could use `DBMS_COMPRESSION.COMP_ADVANCED` instead.

Comment: After change you suggested I have following error: PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'GET_COMPRESSION_RATIO'